# TypeScript vs Node JSON implied object member scope difference

Tags: typescript

Very basic scope question, new to TypeScript.

How can I make the following work in tsc 4.3.5, the way it works in node 14.17.1 - I am referring to the count object member reference which the function cannot find (TS2304). Seems like either I somehow get an implicit 'this' effect, or just have it relax variable definitions into the global space.

Is there a way to allow this to work **with no source changes**? This kind of usage expectation is all over my templating scenario. I don't mind if its relaxed to the point of everything being in a big global namespace together, collisions are not a problem. And I suspect implicit 'this' is not an option since I haven't seen it used anywhere (too bad since that is what I really wanted).

```
//var count = 0;
var b = {
  count: 0,
  incr: function(i) { return (count += i); }
};
console.log(b.incr(1));
console.log(b.incr(2));

// should print
// 1
// 3
```

Comment: Give the `i` argument a type, and `count` is not a free variable, but a property of the object

Comment: Your code is not valid in plain JavaScript any more than it is in Typescript. It gives `Uncaught ReferenceError: count is not defined`.

Comment: @LionelRowe You are correct I got my .js and .ts examples mixed up. So the answer is explicit 'this' is mandatory as in 'this.count' above, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Is there a way to allow this to work with no source changes?"

No. Implicit `this` is not a feature of typescript or javascript. Some languages have it, but there is no syntax equivalent here.

`this` is how to disambiguate between local variables like `var count` and properties of your context `this.count`. If you uncomment that first line then  your code works but it uses the local variable, and not the one defined in the `b` object.

If you want to update the `count` in the `b` object then you *must* reference that property that explicitly via dot notation (`this.count` or `b.count`) or bracket notation (`this['count']` or `b['count']`). There is no working around that fact.